# Reading in Multiple Coordinates on one line (Java)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm having an issue reading in a multiple set of of values that will be saved as x,y coordinates and then stored as nodes. I am writing this program in Java. Some input lines from a text file looks like this:

```
(220 616) (220 666) (251 670) (272 647) # Poly 1

(341 655) (359 667) (374 651) (366 577) # Poly 2

(311 530) (311 559) (339 578) (361 560) (361 528) (336 516) # Poly 3
```

I need to read in each of these coordinates and store them as a node in the format node(x,y). What is the best way to accomplish this? So far I am using a scanner that reads the input file while there is a next line. I save the line in a string s and am trying to parse it like so

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
   String s = nextLine();

   //parse code goes here
   //Currently this is what I have, but I think I'm going about it in a weird way
   String newS = s.substring(s.indexOf("(" + 1, s.indexOf(")"));
   String newX = newS.substring(0, newS.indexOf(" "));
   String newY = newS.substring(newS.indexOf(" ") + 1);
   int x = Integer.parseInt(newX);
   int y = Integer.parseInt(newY);
}
```

I've read several posts above delimiters but I'm still a bit lost. Essentially I need to be able to loop through and save each x,y coordinate as a node that I will then be storing in an array.

Any help helps!
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what you have tried with your parse code?

Comment: Added a bit more to what I have already. The problem is that right now, this only reads in the first coordinate of each line, so I'm looking for a way to expand this to reading all of the coordinates on a single line and store them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is using the .split() method for Strings. Assuming all your lines are formatted the same way

```
String s ="(220 616) (220 666) (251 670) (272 647)";
String[] arr = s.split("\\)\\s*");
```

will make a new array entry every time it comes across a closing bracket " \\) " followed by a space of any length " \\s* "

1:"(220 616"

2:"(220 666"

3:"(251 670"

4:"(272 647"

Then possibly use substring() to pick out the numbers you need, turn it into a point, then add it to an arraylist of points.

eg.

```
    String s ="(220 616) (220 666) (251 670) (272 647)";
    String[] arr = s.split("\\)\\s*");
    List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
    for (String anArr : arr){
        int x = Integer.parseInt(anArr.substring(1,anArr.indexOf(" ")));
        int y = Integer.parseInt(anArr.substring(anArr.indexOf(" ") + 1, anArr.length()));
        Point p = new Point(x,y);
        points.add(p);
        System.out.println(p);
    }
```

gives the output

```
    java.awt.Point[x=220,y=616]
    java.awt.Point[x=220,y=666]
    java.awt.Point[x=251,y=670]
    java.awt.Point[x=272,y=647]
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to isolate the coordinates

```
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {   
       String currentLine = scanner.nextLine();
       Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9]");
       Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher(currentLine);

       while (myMatcher.find()) {
           String[] coordinatesSplit = myMatcher.group().split(" ");
           int x = Integer.parseInt(coordinatesSplit[0]);
           int y = Integer.parseInt(coordinatesSplit[1]);
       }
    }
```